# NGINX throws Bad Gateway error

Tags: php, nginx

I have a PHP application running on Ubuntu with Nginx.
It uses PHP 7.1.

I'm getting Timeout error after 60s exactly.
I added all the options below one by one and tested. The error changed from Timeout to Bad Gateway.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
        keepalive_timeout 600s;
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_send_timeout 180s;
        proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    }
```

One pattern I have observed is that before these changes it was throwing Timeout error exactly after 60seconds.

I've increased max_execution_time in php.ini from 30 to 300.

Comment: what is the output of `ls -alh /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock`

Comment: $ ls -alh /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug 31 09:38 /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock

Comment: Remove all timeouts. Check how much time your script usually takes and why does it need more than 60 secs

Comment: To help people debug such issues, I just finished the article and published it few mins ago http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/